# Voip UDP adding a sequence number (preparing for packetloss)

Tags: java, udp, voip

Note: I'm currently learning UDP and how effective a VoIP system would be in comparison with a TCP system, I've already done TCP so please no one comment TCP is better etc..

So I'm trying to add a sequence number to the packets so I can order them on the server end and prepare for any lost packets, by repeating the previous for example

**Problem**: I read a stackoverflow that said using DataOutputStreams is a good way to go about this, so I implemented it. however when using the code  `dos.writeInt(sequenceNumber++);` I get a horrible repetitive crackle. I was thinking maybe the problem is the amount of bytes that im sending.

Thank you in advance, any pointers will be great

```
  boolean running = true;
    try {
        AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder();
        int sequenceNumber = 0;
        while (running) {
                byte[] tempBuffer = recorder.getBlock();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
                dos.write(tempBuffer);
                dos.writeInt(sequenceNumber++);

                dos.flush();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(baos.toByteArray(), baos.size(), clientIP, PORT);
                sending_socket.send(sendPacket);

        }
        recorder.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
```

Server end:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        byte[] temp = new byte[512];
        try {
            // CODE TO RECEIVE THE AUDIO
            AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
            int expectedValue = 0;
            while (running) {

                //Vector used to store audio blocks (32ms/512bytes each)
                Vector<byte[]> voiceVector = new Vector<>();

                // creates a new udp packet to receive the audio
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                receiving_socket.receive(packet);

                // creates a byte array from the data
                byte[] udpPacketBytes = packet.getData();
                ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(udpPacketBytes);

                DataInputStream dos = new DataInputStream(baos);

                int receivedValue = dos.readInt();
                if (receivedValue == expectedValue) {
                    byte[] filteredByteArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(udpPacketBytes, 4, udpPacketBytes.length - 4);
                    voiceVector.add(filteredByteArray);

                    Iterator<byte[]> voiceItr = voiceVector.iterator();

                    while (voiceItr.hasNext()) {
                        player.playBlock(voiceItr.next());
                    }

                } else {
                    // play the previous again
                    byte[] filteredByteArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(temp, 4, temp.length - 4);
                    voiceVector.add(filteredByteArray);
                    Iterator<byte[]> voiceItr = voiceVector.iterator();

                    while (voiceItr.hasNext()) {
                        player.playBlock(voiceItr.next());
                    }

                    // play the current one
                    byte[] fba = Arrays.copyOfRange(udpPacketBytes, 4, udpPacketBytes.length - 4);
                    voiceVector.add(fba);

                    Iterator<byte[]> vItr = voiceVector.iterator();

                    while (vItr.hasNext()) {
                        player.playBlock(vItr.next());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(receivedValue + " " + expectedValue);
                expectedValue = receivedValue + 1;
                temp = packet.getData();


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("yo");
        }
        //Close the socket
        receiving_socket.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing the sequence number but you are not reading or removing it so your sequence number ends up in the audio.

I suggest you read the same format you write.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I've read a lot of your answers prior to this post Peter. I've edited my server code but the problem still persists

Comment: So I've read it as you can see in the Server side, how do I Remove it?

Comment: When you get the bytes, you have to skip the 4 bytes you read an int. Ideally you could make `playBlock` do this by giving an offset and length, otherwise you need to take a copy of the byte[] which is actually audio.

Comment: Ah I see, are the sequence bytes always added to the end? so would I need to only play the first 508 bytes?

Comment: You appear to be added the sequence number at the start.

Comment: Check my edit, I swapped it so the sequence number is at the end. Is that what you'd have done?

Comment: @user3667111 I would have the sequence number at the start as you had it, I would also make sure it's not in the audio as well, which is something you have to do either way.

Comment: @user3667111 I don't know which AudioPlayer you are using, but like I said I would see if you can specify the offset and length of the byte[] to play from and use that form instead. This will allow you to skip the bytes which are not audio.

Comment: So you'd do it within the AudioPlayer rather than when you're iterating through?

Comment: Also may I ask, if you were preparing for lost packets how would you use the sequence number to determine the situation?

Comment: I changed my code to prepare for packet loss, so it repeats the previous byte, as saved by temp, this the right direction?

Comment: @user3667111 You can detect the loss of a packet if there is a jump in the sequence number. You need to send a packet back to the sender to let the know if you have either a) received packets up to N or b) it must retransmit from N